# SQL server LineString columns to geography columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE SpatialProvince(GlineTR geography) 

INSERT INTO SpatialProvince (GlineTR) 
select CAST(Linestring as geography) from provinceTR
```

MY data has columns called Linestring (i.e This is one row

> LINESTRING (92661.70218750089 4290234.88671875, 92575.35796874762 4290226.28109375, 92371.89531250298 4290203.133437499, 92032.390625 4290199.395624999, 91732.92562499642 4290161.293906249, 91563.55375000089 4290124.568593752, 91372.52499999851 4289997.077187501, 91148.19968750328 4289813.454999998, 91001.99328125268 4289728.095312499, 90974.37484374642 4289576.49953125, 90954.56328125298 4289244.919374999, 90899.67828124762 4288912.90265625, 90843.10265625268 4288732.16390625, 90803.5823437497 4288602.060781252, 90658.859375 4288456.404218748, 90560.02265624702 4288397.732656252, 90484.20921874791 4288375.291562501, 90309.20046874881 4288322.952500001, 90158.73265624791 4288170.090781249, 89985.11046875268 4287988.098437499, 89852.6881249994 4287784.92984375, 89842.4215625003 4287679.87125, 89842.13953124732 4287676.763593748, 89878.18921875209 4287590.71875, 89925.7932812497 4287519.157187499, 89944.00703124702 4287420.835156251, 89921.984375 4287328.567812499, 89843.5501562506 4287003.510781251, 89899.9801562503 4286651.126406249, 89909.26828125119 4286327.009687498, 89909.28203125298 4286325.7346875, 89909.35562500358 4286323.074375, 89900.19671875238 4286085.2465625, 89875.20187500119 4285958.90640625, 89797.17062500119 4285867.978593752, 89641.05687499791 4285686.235624999, 89460.40718749911 4285612.232031249, 89232.75859375298 4285552.201718751, 89121.86093749851 4285522.192343749, 88940.82078125328 4285484.232343748, 88759.5814062506 4285460.688749999, 88624.77109374851 4285480.883593749, 88454.86093749851 4285493.502968751, 88338.04640624672 4285515.89109375)

and I have to get smaller number for latitude and longitude. Cuz I am getting an error "Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees." How can I do that ?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `geometry` not `geography`. Because `geography` obviously cannot be more than 90 degrees latitude. See fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a61c3c76619c8272ead9e5502ee99da

Comment: Guys, you see my one row, I am trying to convert this "geo" object for sql server. Spatial data. You know what I mean. How can you do that ?

Comment: Like I said, I think you are using the wrong data type, you need `CAST(... AS geometry)` not `geography`

Comment: Okey bro, I will try. I hope It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
INSERT INTO SpatialProvince (GlineTR) 
SELECT CAST(TRIM(STRING_SPLIT(Linestring, ',')) as geography) 
FROM provinceTR
```

You should also read this here: [T-SQL geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-ver15)